# What is the "§" key for on an Apple keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

What is the purpose of the "§" symbol on an Apple keyboard?

Comment: Just as a comment, my Belgian run-of-the-mill Azerty keyboard has the §-key as well (it's under the 6).
Like here (though this isn't my keyboard) http://www.typematrix.com/shop/images/products/2030-skin-037-b-french-belgium-azerty_860x360__2012-12-02.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the [section sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign). It's often used in legal documents along with the [pilcrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) like this "§5 ¶1" meaning "section 5 paragraph 1".

Answer (score 5):

The name of that glyph is section sign. Some people use it in writing to refer to sections of documents. If you don't use it, you can try remapping it to something more usefull for you.